# Is a semicolon or comma more appropriate in this case?

Tags: commas, semicolons

I'm wondering whether a semicolon or comma is more appropriate for the following phrase:

> Whether or not it succeeds depends on the third option; namely, how well the program computes the values.

> Whether or not it succeeds depends on the third option, namely, how well the program computes the values.

It seems intuitive to me that the semicolon seems more appropriate. However, "namely, how well the program computes the values" does not seem like an independent clause (it seems dependent on "Whether or not it succeeds depends on the third option", which *is* an independent clause), so I'm unsure if it is technically correct. On the other hand, the use of the/a comma in the second option just seems intuitively wrong, given the resulting structure.

So which one of these is the correct (or "best") way to structure this phrase?

Comment: I think you are correct in your assessment. It looks better as a comma than a semi-colon.

Comment: @Elliot So you think that the comma is more appropriate?

Comment: I agree, the comma fits better.

Comment: Normally when we've to introduce a new item, we often use a colon or an emdash. And semicolon is more reserved for connecting independent clauses that are closely related to each other. Comma might not be the preferred punctuation mark there.

Comment: @user405662 It seems to me that neither are appropriate for this situation, no? Also, are you saying that the comma is probably not the appropriate punctuation mark for this case? If so, then what would you suggest as the more appropriate punctuation mark?

Comment: A colon preferably: because you are introducing or describing the third option, and it makes sense to halt the flow of your words a little. Comma is rather abrupt there. But it's just my opinion.

Comment: @user405662 interesting, I think you make some good points.

Comment: @Pointer, The - Yes, that is what I think. If I had the citation to go with it then I would have put it down as an answer. The "namely" and explanation are to be spoken as an aside and as such the comma gives the speaker a pause to set off the additional idea.

Comment: The test for whether a semicolon is acceptable is if you could write each clause as a separate sentence and they'd make sense. In this case, it wouldn't make much sense to start a sentence with "namely, ..."

Comment: @Barmar So what punctuation mark do you think is most appropriate?

Comment: @ThePointer I agree with the comments that comma is appropriate.